# The /review page needs to be able to handle more than just problem posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

The `/review` page displays questions matching the following criteria:

- first answers from new users
- first questions from new users
- late answers provided by low-rep users
- low-quality posts; I don't know the quality algorithm, but it presumably changes rarely if at all

EDIT to include info from comments:
<del>If I understand correctly, the posts listed under all of these categories will never change. That is, once a post is added, it will never fail to meet the criteria (unless it is edited, which is rare).</del> The posts listed in the last category will never change. The posts listed in the others will eventually disappear as the OPs get more rep. (That seems like a flawed system to me, though; a user's first post doesn't automatically improve just because the user got better after writing that post.)

As a result, the number of posts listed on the review page will increase steadily over time, while the percentage of posts that actually need attention will diminish. To resolve this issue, we need a way to get non-problematic posts off the list.

EDIT to merge in the contents of [a duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82062/approve-question-flag-in-review):
There should be a "mark as okay" button that will remove valid posts from the review page. It could require a number of users (three?) to click it before the post is removed. This will clean up the question list and thus make it easier to review.

Comment: Actually, the first 3 will cease to qualify when the user ceases to be new/low-rep.

Comment: Agreed, I took a sweep through the review page and noticed lots of posts that were not problematic. (Or problematic enough to flag)

Comment: And the first *two* will stop qualifying when a user is no longer "new".

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure about those. I originally wrote more about each case, but decided it was too much text and cut it all. The last bullet point is the most problematic anyways. (@Grace @Shog)

Comment: If we extrapolate from the forthcoming edition review system, we need an 'approve' to match the current 'reject'.

Comment: Has this been committed yet?

Comment: +1 for the "flag as OK" button, as long as it is only available to reviewers with a minimum amount of reputation, e.g. 2k. It would definitely reduce the posts in the review page if posts that were considered acceptable by, say, 5 such reviewers were removed. I, for, one am getting sick and tired of seeing the same posts over and over again...

Comment: Apart from a "flag as OK" which removes a question from /review for everyone, **it would be great to have a "hide for me" button**. Reviewing would be much more fun if I could actually see the list get shorter with every answer I read, even if I decide to neither upvote nor flag (for example since I leave a comment suggesting improvements).

Comment: @PopularDemand does http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them/110414#110414 resolve this?

Comment: I believe it does, @waffles.

Answer (score 6):

This has been resolved: see [Allow marking posts as reviewed on /review and hide them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them/110414#110414)

Comment: "not very bad" != "good enough to up vote"

Comment: @Ian a users first upvote on the website is a pretty special moment, I would argue that if it is not worth a downvote and is helpful in some way it is worth an upvote being the first post

Comment: I used to think this until SO got more "new" (none trained programmer) users then it could cope with

Comment: @waffles: The low quality tab also features editing besides voting and flagging. Editing the contributions listed there is a good way to keep the quality of a community high, especially on new communities...

Comment: @Tom yes totally agree there.

Answer (score 4):

I think to understand `/review` you have to realize that there is

1) Stack Overflow, which is 1000x larger than everything else

and

2) well, everything else

Stated another way, when you have *THREE THOUSAND SIX HUNDRED* plus new questions every day -- and many times that in answers -- your strategy has to change radically. That's why **you must hone in on specific tags on the /review page on Stack Overflow**.

[image: review page by tag]

(for comparison SF and SU get about *ONE HUNDRED* new questions per day).

If you attempt to review "everything", you will either burn out or give up entirely.

Either

- drilling down to specific tags

or

- reviewing a random sample

… are the *only sane things to do* in this scenario, and that's exactly why we switch to random ordering once you view anything on /review that has more than 90 entries.

(the other problem is that default sorting by votes leads to a "rich get richer, poor get poorer" paradigm where the good stuff gets super-up-voted and the bad stuff gets pummeled into sub-atomic particles)

Comment: it's also worth noting that since this question was asked, we enabled "review" showing on the homepage where "tools" would go for users between 200 and 10k rep -- and review is a pseudo-tab on the tools as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?pagesize=15&filter=week&tag=c%23 filtered to c#

Comment: @waffles http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?pagesize=15&filter=day&tag=c%23 filtered by day. There's your precious sort order..