# Allow marking posts as reviewed on /review and hide them

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

I think it would be useful if reviewers could mark posts on the `/review` page as reviewed and found acceptable. The marked posts would then be hidden from the reviewing user. If enough reviewers (3-5) mark a post as reviewed, it should be removed from the `/review` page for everyone.

This would make it easier to spot the problematic posts, as not everybody has to review every post. It would minimize the duplication of effort and make the whole process more efficient.

There should probably be a reputation limit on this power, I'd say 3k as I would rate that responsibility similar to close votes. Moderators could get deciding votes there, as they already get for close votes.

Comment: This sounds like a useful complement to the "approve edits privilege."

Comment: Being able to 'clear the queue' from /Review would do a great deal to satisfy my primitive insect brains need for a goal, and substantially increase my use of said page.

Comment: Also, I wonder if this could be used to refine the detection of good vs. bad content.  We're already flagging the bad, why not track what doesn't belong in the review area?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The /review page needs to be able to handle more than just problem posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/the-review-page-needs-to-be-able-to-handle-more-than-just-problem-posts)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Completed:

- on the `/review` we renamed the "show all" link to "review question/answer".
- we keep track of all the reviews you perform

[image: review]

- we provide you with progress stats
- we suppress posts that were reviewed by 2 other people from the lists
- we suppress posts you already reviewed from the list

[image: stats]

Comment: Is there any lower rep limit for users to suppress posts for everyone? I seem to be able to review posts as a completely new user. Even as an anonymous user, I get the link (even though it doesn't do anything). Reviewing's no good if the reviewers don't have a clue, either.

Comment: Do I need to do something to see other than all zeros for my stats? I did quite a bit of reviewing this morning and see all zeros still.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I have the habit of clicking the title link to go see the question. I have to click Review Question to have my reviewing counted, right?

Comment: @waffles, I just tested it, looks great, but it would still be nice to have stickiness of the settings.

Comment: @lunboks huge oversight on my part ... you now need to "Established User" priv to review - to be deployed later

Comment: I don't know if only "reviewed by **2** other people" is enough to safely remove it from the list.I think some sort of “machine learning” system would be best, that learns what combination of factors are most likely to get a post acted on in the review tab, including the number of people that have reviewed it in the past and not acted on it.

Comment: @waffles, __holy moly, it's sticky now__.  You are my hero.

Comment: The post shouldn't be marked as reviewed simply by clicking that link. It would be better to have a "mark as reviewed" next to "edit|close|flag" to explicitly mark a post as ok. I think this would be intuitive and would leave you the option to not decide if that post is good. For example I might not want to edit a post just because I looked at it, even if it would need editing.

Comment: IMHO this isn't convenient. Normally a post starts like an answer and further down it turns into a bunch of questions making it not an answer. Or, the poster ignored the preview window and half of his/her HTML/XML-style answer simply is not visible. The current situation seems to accept the post as soon as I click "review question" and don't do anything. IMHO, this "silence is consent" kind of way will leave a bunch of posts that would have been modified otherwise. I prefer the "looks good to me, but I'm not the pro on that topic/tag to qualify it as good or bad" way.

Comment: @waffles I'm assuming the post goes off the list based on rep? On SO with 5k rep once I've reviewed something, seems I don't see it again, but on SF : `160 rep`, especially with the much lower incoming post volume, I'm seeing the same list over and over. Is it rep or badge based?