# What happened to the review link in the top menu?

Tags: support, review

Earlier there was a review link (a link to https://stackoverflow.com/review/) in the top menu but now there's not. What happened to it?

Here's how the top menu looks for me:

[image: No review link]

Since I can see the review link on sites where I have more reputation I guess the amount of reputation required to have it shown has been increased. Am I right?

Comment: Looks like it is currently visible to users having >1k or >2k reputation points. I can see the link on SO but it is hidden on MSO.

Comment: Could be related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them/110414#110414 - see waffle's last comment - "Established user" is 1k rep.

Comment: @Mat I noticed this the last week or something so that may be it.

Comment: Looks like the trigger is 1k. M.SO I have 1.4k and can see it. SU I have 3.4k and can see it. SF I have 930 and can't see it.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the review section is still accessible if you type out the URL or bookmark it.

Comment: I just downed the requirement to 100 rep ... and added the awesome progress meter ... we need to update the answer here...

Comment: I used to see the link (when I had around 300 rep ... or maybe even less!) and I did do a few reviews. Although I can manually go to SO.com/review (the link is no longer there) I notice 500 rep is now required for the most basic review tasks. I suspect this may be because I failed a few of the 'tests' :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have 1000 rep (be an "Established user") to see "review" link. See comments to these posts:

- [Allow marking posts as reviewed on /review and hide them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them/110414#110414)

Comment: Have you got a link to any source confirming this? Is there anything else that triggers the appearance of the review link, e.g. getting the Deputy badge at <1000 reputation?

Comment: I asked similar question and got comment about it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110880/165129

Comment: Could you please include the relevant information by editing your answer?

Comment: confirmed ... I bumped up the review requirement, in general we want established users reviewing

Comment: @waffles This requirement makes sense in most cases but not in all, therefore I've put forth a suggestion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110935/have-the-review-link-appear-for-anyone-with-the-deputy-badge

Comment: @AndreiPetrenko Do you mind updating your answer according to Waffles comment to my question and his updated answer I linked in the former comment?

Comment: i used to have the Review Capabilities on several Stack Exchange sites and now I don't have the link anymore, is this like a sliding scale for the "Established User" Status?