# Where has "review" link gone?

Tags: support, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the review link in the top menu?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110761/what-happened-to-the-review-link-in-the-top-menu)

There used to be a [review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) in my top bar on SO, but it's not there anymore. Can anyone explain 
where she had gone?

Comment: Which site are you talking about?

Comment: @AnnaLear Sorry, updated my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do know about that, I just wonder why link was removed. BTW linked question has no answers too.

Comment: @Andrei: It was an oversight on Waffles' part. Users must have 1000 reputation (be an "established user") to see the link.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to be an "established user" to access it, it's just not as easy.  You'd have to type in the URL yourself.  If you go that far, I'd say you are definitely dedicated and you'll probably earn the necessary rep in no time.