# Customizable top menu bar

Tags: feature-request

Would it be reasonable to give SE user ability to customize his/her top menu appearance? Some users tend to review posts, other prefer to chat. Maybe it would be better to let them decide for themselves, what links they prefer to see on top?

By the way, I don't think registered users really need "about" link hanging in the top bar.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer you question but you could change SE yourself with something like Greasemonkey https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is very useful. You mentioned two links which are already there. What links do you *not* see that you would want to *add*? Because if you don't want to chat, just... don't click that link.

In addition, it could actually be *detrimental* because:

- It may introduce new bugs
- It may be confusing
- It will cause more confusion when people report bugs / ask questions. Now we have to ask what everyone has their top bar configured like.
- It takes the team's time from building more important features.

Plus, your [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) doesn't have any [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775). I could be convinced to upvote this if your post had a clear example of why this is needed, *with a freehand circle around it*.

Comment: As for me, I don't see "review" link and  I really don't need  "chat" link really. I prefer tor replace "chat" with "blog" (with that neat little notification about new posts).

Comment: You don't have all those already? I do...

Comment: And don't it cause confusion when you just make some changes quietly (with already mentioned "review", for example)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that comment... but I'm sure the answer is no, because I am not confused by these sites. I like the layout quite well.

Comment: Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110761/165129. It seems that removal of "review" did cause some confusion already :-).

Comment: It should never have been there (for you) in the first place :-)

Comment: Sure :-). But these changes make me feel like a sheep.

Comment: I can see how you feel that way when things *disappear*. That normally won't happen, it was just a fluke.