# What does 'Actioned' mean?

Tags: support, badges, review, review-badges

The Reviewer badge description is:

> 1000 reviews, over 200 actioned

What does ***actioned*** mean in this context please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [New bronze badge for "reviewing"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/new-bronze-badge-for-reviewing)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To review a post is to press "review answer/question" on a post on the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) (which makes the post expand so that it may be reviewed). "Actioned" refers to having done any of the following on a reviewed post:

- Upvoted
- Downvoted
- Edited
- Commented
- Voted to Close
- Flagged
- Deleted

When you get the [Strunk & White badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) on a site you get a tracker on the review page which tracks reviews and actions on reviews. On Stack Overflow it looks like this for me:

[image: Review tracker]

The [badge Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer) and the review tracker are due to a recent change, see [Have the review link appear for anyone with the Deputy badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110935/have-the-review-link-appear-for-anyone-with-the-deputy-badge/111010#111010).

Comment: Ah got it thanks. I'd assumed that an action was that another user had commented, upvoted etc, an edit that I had made.