# Review outside the "review section"

Tags: discussion, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between reviewing and regular activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111764/what-is-the-difference-between-reviewing-and-regular-activity)

I find the current method of collecting review statistics a bit strange.

For example, if I review a question, which happens to be the OP's first question, from the main page and take some action(s) on it, these actions are not added to my review stats. On the other hand, if I first look up the exact same question in the review section and take the actions from there, they *are* added to my stats.

I would find it more intuitive that actions performed on questions/answers that are in the review section are added to my stats *no matter how I got there*.

So, I was wondering what the rationale is for the current behavior.

Comment: My guess would be that the current system (the browser sends a "I reviewed this" request when loading posts on certain pages) is cheaper than verifying whether a post is actually in a review queue for every action you take.

Comment: I expect there to be a dupe on this _checks_

Comment: _Comes back emptyhanded and surprised_

Comment: @Manishearth: Yes, I expected the same thing but couldn't find anything either.

Comment: @random: Thanks for finding the dupe:-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of the badges associated with these stats is to encourage people to use the reviewing tools instead of only acting via the front page or some other, narrow scoped things. The idea being that things which might otherwise have been missed can get caught via /review (and the 10K tools which do count for it also)

If you could get the badges just by doing things on the front page alone that would negate that purpose.

Comment: But the net effect would still be the same: you reviewed somebody's first question, for example. You could still get to the badges faster by using /review.

Comment: @Job - the net effect isn't the same on the larger scale issue though. You reviewed somebody's first question that happened to be posted at the right time for you to be sat there in your timezone, when 50% of the rest of the SO users are also awake and looking at the front page. /review shows them in a random order. /review spreads the attention around a bit more evenly.