# Make the Epic, Generalist, Reviewer badges Gold badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Silly suggestion perhaps, but it seems like the Epic, Generalist, and Reviewer badges are especially hard to attain (228, 288, and 162 respectively).

All three have less recipients than Stellar Question (500+), and Reviewer even less than the prestigious Marshal badge (198).

Maybe they should be made Gold too?

Just a thought.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for Epic to be a gold badge because we already provide a more difficult to obtain badge along the same lines: [Legendary](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary). That one is the gold badge. I disagree about the others, but I don't have a persuasive or witty justification.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the feedback. I agree about Epic/Legendary, but perhaps Epic is slightly too hard? *shrugs* was just a thought.

Comment: Reviewer is not hard. It just takes a bit of work.

Comment: I worked really hard for the Marshal badge, under the old rules that is!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make the conclusion that rare badges are hard and need to be gold. So I don't agree.

I'm surprised that the reviewer badge is rare. It's one of the easiest badges (you don't need another person to get it). You just need to invest some time and use the reviewer tools.

Generalist is a special case. You get it easy if you are active in the popular tags. And its almost imposible to get if you are not that active in these tags. But that doesn't justify to make it a gold one.

Comment: Reviewer badge is relatively new (introduced [less than half year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111329/165773)) - this may have something to do with it being rare