# Will there be new badges introduced over time? and retire some badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Will there be new badges introduced over time? and retire some badges? What is the procedure to do so? Is there a public voting system to introduce/retire badges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New badges appear from time-to-time, and some actually change their definition, but not very frequently. See, for example, the list of [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/168244):

- 2013-01-10: [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed)
- 2012-09-21: [Custodian](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian), [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) & [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward)
- 2012-06-08: [Caucus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus) & [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent)
- 2012-02-07: [Research Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant)
- 2011-11-08: [Reviewer badge has been changed to a silver badge with the requirements increased to 1000 reviews and acting on at least 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111329/168244)
- 2011-11-07: [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer)
- 2011-08-24: [Analytical](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical) (retired)
- 2011-08-22: [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal)
- 2011-08-15: [Excavator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator) & [Archeologist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist)
- 2011-08-06: [Proofreader](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1276/proofreader)
- 2011-07-07: [Synonymizer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1224/synonymizer)
- 2011-05-09: [Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi)

...to name a few. These are not introduced by voting, but with site changes.

Comment: HOW DID YOU GET THAT HAT IT IS SO COOL

Comment: @Pëkka: Over on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)... however, we don't have the Close Reviewer problem over there.

Comment: I see! Yeah, that could be difficult to get on SO proper.

Comment: @Pëkka It's not that diffucult. You just have to spend a bit of time waiting for posts to show up in each queue...