# Edit workflow uncomfortable in the "Review question/answer" section

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

The new "Review" options introduced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them/110414#110414) are a bit awkward to use for editing.

Both saving and canceling an edit that you started from the review page bring you to the question or answer's normal page rather than back to the review page. So you need to go back twice to return to the review section.

(And that doesn't always get you back to exactly where you were if you had some items reviewed (thus expanded) before you started editing, though that might be a browser bug.)

Could this be changed to bring you back to the review page, or is this by-design to make sure you actually check the result of the edit *in situ*?

Comment: well the real solution is to have inline edit there ... will work on it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just implemented inline edit in review, should be way easier to edit stuff.

Comment: Excellent, much more editor-friendly. Thanks!

Comment: I was going to ask a related question, but found this one. Can a similar change be made for when you're reviewing suggested edits and choose Improve? At the moment, that pulls you out of the reviewing workflow and lands you on the question's page.

Comment: I just came to ask the same thing as @joran. What about it waffles, should we ask another question?

Comment: @Benjol sure post a separate request on it

Comment: OK, done. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115088/improve-suggested-edit-workflow-currently-not-ideal