# "Improve" suggested edit workflow from reviews is  currently not ideal, have it trigger in-line editing or open in new tab

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, inline-editor

Currently, if you go to improve a suggested edit, you jump out of the review page, and it's awkward getting back. It's not impossible, just awkward, which makes you (well me, in any case) hesitate to bother to improve.

I haven't got any great suggestions or preferences. I guess in-line edit would be the best (as per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110773/edit-workflow-uncomfortable-in-the-review-question-answer-section) similar request for the other review tabs). Another alternative would be to have it open in a new tab - anything which doesn't result in having me navigate out of the review queue.

(In passing, one thing to look out for if it *is* inline is that you need to match the same width as the final post: because one of the things I like to edit for is to avoid horizontal scrollbars on code sections)

Comment: +1 Death to horizontal scroll bars.