# Can we improve Suggested Edits in-place?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Improve” suggested edit workflow from reviews is  currently not ideal, have it trigger in-line editing or open in new tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115088/improve-suggested-edit-workflow-from-reviews-is-currently-not-ideal-have-it)

As per [my non-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow/135805#135805) to the question on UI annoyances in the Suggested Edit queue...

When choosing to 'Improve' a suggested edit, you're taken to the stand-alone edit page and on saving your edit, returned to the question page (***not*** back to the Edit queue).

Can we not just edit in-place *à la* the other Review queues (Late Answers, etc.)?

If I'm taken away from the queue each time, I'm much more likely to wander off and browse questions than carry on editing. At the very least, make it open in a new window so we don't have to!

Comment: I tend to open the link to the suggestion in a new tab when I improve. Then after editing, I just close the tab and get back to the review page. But I'd prefer if I didn't need that workaround, +1.

Comment: ["Improve" suggested edit workflow from reviews is  currently not ideal, have it trigger in-line editing or open in new tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115088)

Comment: @Sathya No idea how I missed that. Bounty duly added.

Comment: I remember that because I'd added a [bounty to it.. with no response](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/115088/revisions)