# Bounty grace period - no answers - award it to who exactly?

Tags: support, bug, bounties

The bounty I offered on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115088/improve-suggested-edit-workflow-from-reviews-is-currently-not-ideal-have-it) is now in its grace period and the information box tells me:

> **you must award this bounty as soon as possible**

But there are no answers - what do I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Related: [Why encourage bounty awarding when there are no answers at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139359/131713)

Comment: Will this be fixed someday ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

So, nothing for you *to* do.

Admittedly, not being *able* to award a bounty at all makes this a bad message - this can certainly be seen as a bug.

Comment: That's fine - perhaps the wording should be conditional on whether the bounty can actually be awarded?

Comment: @Widor - Either that or be changed to encompass both cases.

Comment: Is there a reason why questions with no replies at all also result in a bounty forfeit? (I read the FAQ and I understand why it should be forfeited if there are answers and the bounty is not awarded). No big deal but it happened to me and I didn't understand what was up.

Comment: @skinnyTOD - To avoid people simply getting attention to a post (good or bad). The idea is that you are paying for a featured "slot" with some rep.

Comment: Perhaps there's a case for two types of bounty - a 'promo' one and a 'prize' one. The promo one would simply be a fixed fee to make the question more visible - the promoter loses their 'fee' and _no-one_ gets the bounty, whether there are good answers or none. The 'prize' one is variable and goes to the best answer as judged by the bounty-starter, but is refundable if you don't get an answer.

Comment: @Oded: OK- thanks. I guess that makes sense. In my case, I just wanted help with my damned question and when I got no answers, forfeiting it just seemed to add insult to desperation... ;-)

Comment: Now that you're a dev you have the power to make what you suggest happen. :)

Comment: I get ***This question had a bounty worth +50 reputation from lostsock that ended 9 hours ago. You have 14 hours to award the bounty*** , but there's no answers, so maybe the last sentence shouldn't appear? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233560/flagging-a-deleted-post-should-not-give-you-dont-have-permission since it's not possible to award a bounty since 0 answers

Answer (score 24):

On a side note: Answers that are posted during the grace period are still eligible for bounties, so the grace period still makes sense.

In any case, the wording

> **you must award this bounty as soon as possible**

is misleading. There's nothing you **must** do. Even if there are two, twenty or two hundred answers, you don't have to do *anything* if none of the answers is good enough.

In my opinion,

> **If you're going to award the bounty, you must do so as soon as possible.**

sounds better.