# Flagging a deleted post should not give "you don't have permission"

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, deleted-posts

If you try to flag a post that has been deleted since you loaded the question page, the system returns a rather unfortunate error message:

> You don't have permission to use this type of flag

Actually, the problem isn't that you don't have permission to use the type of flag (in the particular case that happened to me, a spam flag on a question), but rather that the post has been deleted.

If the post has been deleted in the interim, the message should reflect that fact. So for example:

> This post has been deleted.

Or, to be even more explicit:

> You cannot flag this post because it has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. For a minute I thought some moderator had taken away my ability to flag posts.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Nah, we aren't usually *that* evil. ;)

Comment: This just happened to me too. It's a terrible error message because it makes the user think that they have had a flagging privileged revoked. I then tested to downvote on an answer that was going to be deleted as NAA, so kept the window open, it gives an acceptable error message of *"this post has been deleted, deleted posts can not be voted on"*. So the flag on deleted answer should be changed to something similar

Comment: Still happened to me just now.

Comment: Does this still happen?  I have tried to reproduce this and haven't been able to, so any additional details from the victims would be much appreciated.

Comment: @BenCollins I'd be glad to give it a try if we can just set up the scenario. (Shouldn't be very difficult.) Ping me into a chat room.

Comment: … or do nothing and reload.

Comment: [This post today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378853/you-dont-have-the-permission-to-use-this-type-of-flag-when-casting-a-spam-fla) indicates that it's gotten undone again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the only way this ever happens is if a user opens the flagging dialog, a post is deleted, and then the user submits a flag (other than "needs moderator attention").

Thanks for reporting and helping me reproduce this.  It should be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Yes, these are the steps. We can confirm and test the fix the next time we get Drupal spam. All of us flag and the spam gets nuked while our flag dialog is open, so we see it all the time. Will check from the Tavern and let you know. Because of the high frequency, we see it very often.

Comment: so... status-completed?

Comment: @Briam I usually like to see it go out first, but because you asked, ....ok. :-)

Comment: Somebody ping me here when this is confirmed fixed so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: It's fixed. Now, this message is displayed http://i.stack.imgur.com/a8c5K.png

Answer (score 2):

Does not seem to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) any more, just now I got this on a rude/abusive post on Hinduism.SE:

[image]

Link to the deleted answer for reference: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27323