# "You don't have the permission to use this type of flag" when casting a spam flag

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, spam, deleted-posts

Today I attempted to flag a question as spam on Stack Overflow; however, it was deleted the same moment as I cast the flag. The UI shows a popup

> You don't have the permission to use this type of flag

which, according to the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag on these bug reports from 2014:

- [What does "You don't have the permission to use this type of flag" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215481/295232)
- [Flagging a deleted post should not give "you don't have permission"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233560/295232)

should not happen anymore. Both have an answer from 2018 which indicate the fix broke again. A better text would be

> This post has been deleted, so your flag couldn't be processed.

or something like that.

---

[image]

Comment: An answer to the latter question [posted in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309744/377214) indicates this came up again at that time.

Comment: Ah right, I missed that one. Still, the proper procedure is to post a new bug report, right? Especially if it had already been fixed a couple of years ago?

Comment: Yes, that's the proper procedure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We were unable to reproduce your issue. However, we can confirm that we have checks in place if a post is deleted and display a different message. As such, we have decided to use a broader message as a catchall (“You cannot use this type of flag on this post at the moment”) in lieu of the current permission error.