# Why does the bounty notification seem like a question has answers when there aren't any answers?

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow, bounties

Recently, I activated a bounty of *100* on one of my questions. The bounty grace period has now ended.
Here is a link to my question: [Stack_overflow_bounty_question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525874/peer-to-peer-p2p-communication-between-voip-clients).

The **notification** of bounty appears as given below:

[image: Bounty Question]

---

- My question still not has received any kind of *answer* from anyone. Then *why* does this message or notification appear?

  > Award this bounty to the best answer as soon as possible.

This question is entirely different from the suggested answers. This notification is clearly a bug that is to be fixed according to this answer [bounty-grace-period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137987/bounty-grace-period-no-answers-award-it-to-who-exactly).

---

Comment: ["All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: I have already visited this link. My question is that why this notification appears that `Award this bounty to the best answer`. When there is no more answer?

Comment: I was replying to your second question. Regarding your first one, I guess it shouldn't say "award this bounty" if the question hasn't received any answers; so, yes this seems like a bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bounty grace period - no answers - award it to who exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137987/282094). It certainly seems to be a bit [slow to remove the banner](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58525874/timeline).

Comment: The question is now updated.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your comment. Actually, My Question is If there is no answer, then why this notification Appears as given `" Award this bounty to best answer"`. I know how the bounty system works.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Both the answers in the duplicate link that I suggested exactly answer your question, and the question is also the same as yours (with exception of the delay aspect). It is the other suggested duplicate, about the "X-Y problem", that you might question. If you wish you can clairify in your question why ***my*** suggested duplicate does not apply, or you can leave it as-is and the other reviewers will sort the matter out for you. You are also welcome to find a better duplicate and offer that.

Comment: @Rob my question is about notification or message which is appearing in the above-given picture, Which is (Again), My question hasn't received any answer and notification seems like there are **answers**?

Is there any kind of duplicity?

Comment: Shouldn't the bigger question be that it's telling you to award the bounty after the grace period is over?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Please read the body of the suggested duplicate question. It says **exactly** what you just said. And then, the accepted answer there indicates that it is indeed a bug. What other information are you seeking?

Comment: @Rob I think this bounty notification has to be improved if answers aren't given. That is what I'm asking.

Comment: @Rob It's clearly a bug. If your array has no elements and your asking for the best one possible which is max. Then it would be an empty array.

Comment: There must be an improved notification.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman When anyone votes to close a question it goes into the Review Queue. The first person whom reviews the **other** user's close vote has their name tagged on an **automatically generated** message, unless they delete the comment (that's not the correct thing to do) to avoid people replying to the comment. You are most welcome to agree or disagree with the reviewers, but I don't need to know what your decision is; I'll be doing nothing with the information. People have objected to the wording of the automatic comment, you can do so also,  I'm not an employee and won't be fixing it.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your detailed stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue with the message text. You are being told to award the bounty to the best answer as soon as possible. If no answers currently exist, then "as soon as possible" will be after an answer is posted.

Comment: What does that mean `then "as soon as possible" will be after an answer is posted`?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman It doesn't tell you to award it "now", which would indeed be impossible. It tells you to do it as soon as possible – at the first opportunity you have. It won't necessarily be immediately. It might be after you read all the answers. It might be when you get to a computer. And in some cases it might be after someone posts an answer.

Comment: Let me explain. 1- Bounty grace period is expired. 2- No Answers After that period. 3- No Answer Even bounty is expired. 

When the Answer is not available, not even when a bounty is expired. Then Why this kind of notification. There must be some informative notification. I know my bounty won't be recalculated.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman If the grace period has ended you can't award the bounty anyway, even if there had been answers beforehand.

Comment: @Alex: I think OP is asking what the point of the notification is, then, since they can't do anything about it.

Comment: @V2Blast The original title made it seem like that was indeed the question, but it was then edited to focus instead on the fact that there are no answers (rather than that the bounty is over).