# Text of Bounty Grace Period notice is confusing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, wording, post-notices

> **This [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) has ended.** Answers to this question are eligible for a +50 reputation bounty. You have 19 hours to award this bounty.

The [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70024/when-an-answer-is-deleted-change-person-listed-as-last-modifier) to which I awarded a bounty has exactly one answer, by myself. Which is by definition not eligible for the bounty.

So the message that I get served contains two errors:

> Answers to this question are eligible for a +50 reputation bounty.

No they are not, there is only one answer by me, which is not eligible.

> You have 19 hours to award this bounty.

Again No, there is no answer to award this bounty to.

---

**Can we make the text of this notice either:**

- case dependent, so that it shows a factual correct message dependent on the options that are available for the bounty owner.
- more generic, to for example state: "You have 19 hours to award this bounty to any eligible answer"

<sub>*ps. this was first posted as an answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137987/bounty-grace-period-no-answers-award-it-to-who-exactly/342577#342577) but posted as a separate question per request of [Yaakov Ellis ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis)*</sub>

Comment: @YaakovEllis, this is almost exactly [the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342539/282094) question that a different user asked yesterday; that was closed as a duplicate of the last link in this question, yet the previous question isn't status-review.

Comment: I didn't see the other question yesterday. I saw what Luuklag wrote as an answer to the question on which the other one is a duplicate, and I asked him to open it as a new post, as it was adding new things to the other one. In any event, I marked this one as `status-review`.

Comment: If would be helpful if the warning message was applicable to all situations and suggested a useful course of action. Example: "The bounty you offered on [this question](http://example.com/) is due to expire in X hours (days), if you don't manually award the bounty it may be [awarded automatically or forfeited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/282094).".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of the bounty notice that is shown to the bounty owner has been updated to make it clear that only answers the other users post are eligible for the bounty, and that bounties can only be awarded to eligible answers.

Comment: Would it be possible to include the new texts in your answer Yaakov?