# Have edit link on review page

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, inline-editor

Many times I see a post on the review page, that obviously doesn't need flagging, but it does need editing.  How about giving us an `edit` link which will open up the post, and put you in edit mode directly?  **OR** even better open up an inline editing box (with the full text)?

Think of the `click` and `page-load` savings, cha-ching!

Comment: Can we donate our extra clicks to poor WoW gold farmers in China?

Comment: Oops, completely misread... ignore my duplicate vote please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press review question/answer on any post on the review page there appears an edit link. That is, when you press review question/answer you don't end up at the page of the question/answer but the question/answer is expanded so that you may review it and act appropriately on it. So, since reviewing doesn't take you away from the review page I don't think there's reason to add an edit button.

Here's how it works. You look at posts in the review page and find one which you want to review
[image: Review before expansion]
after you click it the posts expands and you can read it in full format.
[image: Review after expansion]
As seen, there's an edit button at the bottom of the expanded post.

This functionality was newly added, see [Allow marking posts as reviewed on /review and hide them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them/110414#110414) for details.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  It saves a new page being loaded.