# The workflow for reviewing answers doesn't feel quite right

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

On SF I have been actively reviewing questions and answers for some time. The new ability to [mark as reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them) is good and for questions it works well.

I don't know about other people but for me, I (mostly) have to read the question when reviewing an answer. This means that, to mark something as reviewed I have to click the title link to go see the answer and scroll up to question. Come back to review and then click review answer to do the work.

For late answers it's slightly worse, I want to see all the answers as well as the question so I can decide if a question should be protected too (they often need it).

Could clicking the title link display the question and it's answers in review mode so the workflow is improved?

Comment: I agree ... we need some mockups

Comment: Very good point ... This slows things down.

Comment: I agree. I just click the title link out of habit, and then it doesn't count as reviewing. I would like it if clicking the link counted as reviewing without having to click review question first.

Comment: note we now show the question body, something that helps heaps... still thinking of ways to improve

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this yesterday and it helps immensely. I think that, if practical, Paŭlo's suggestion below is great too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would instead prefer to have on the regular question page, if a question or answer is eligible for review for some reason, have a small box with review-tools.

This box would have:

- a small note saying why it should be reviewed (i.e. "first question", "first answer", "late answer", "low quality", "close-vote", or multiple of them, as applicable),
- a button/link to say "is okay" (or "reviewed").

  Clicking this which would have the same effect as now clicking the "review question" or
  "review answer" link on the review page.
- maybe a help link

Of course, this box would appear only for people which have the necessary review privileges.

Here is a mockup (created with Gimp - this is not the right tool for the job):

[image]

This would help me reviewing (or rather "marked as reviewed") posts in the [tags I frequent anyway](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19305/small-tags-sites), without having to go to the review page and clicking through the posts there to mark them as reviewed.

Thus people which like the review page can concentrate on the posts that didn't get review love by users on their regular way through the site.

Comment: This would be good - If a question/answer requires review make it known however you come across it.