# Can I dismiss items from the flag queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools, flags

I was working through the [low quality posts 10k review tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?subtype=lowquality) and editing some of the posts to improve them.

I start to get a little bit frustrated when there are some in there that either

- I have already edited
- I don't know enough about the given subject to make a judgement on
- I just don't really feel like dealing with

I'd like to be able to get them dismiss them from my list so that I don't have to look at them anymore and so that I can move on to the flags that I haven't already seen--and also so that I can have the satisfying feeling of emptying my list.

I think this would also be useful for most of the review tools, including the [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day) page as well as the [close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day)/[first answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day)/[low quality posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day)/[first questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day)/[late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day) pages.

Comment: Related, but not exact dupe: [Allow marking posts as reviewed on /review and hide them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them)

Comment: Posts in the  close/first answers/low quality posts/first questions/late answers pages are already hidden once you've reviewed them, but I support expanding this feature to the other pages.

Comment: The (new since this meta question) [review queues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) work precisely like this: once you review an item, you don't see it again. So this is either [meta-tag:status-completed] (fulfilled by the review queue system) or obsolete (pertaining to old review interfaces that no longer exist).