# Should we be able to mark Suggested Edits as 'Pass' so we don't see the edit again?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add “ignore” button to suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84102/add-ignore-button-to-suggested-edits)

Suppose that a suggested edit is outside your area of expertise.  I think it would be useful to be able to mark it as 'Pass' (or some similar word) so that on any refresh, you are no longer shown that suggested edit.

Particularly during the later evening in the US Pacific time zone, there can be fairly large numbers of suggested edits building up, and it is a nuisance to have to scroll past those that you know you don't want to deal with (or don't know how to deal with).  Or it can happen at any time if you improve a suggested edit, which takes you to the modified question after you're done, and you then go back to review more edits.

Comment: This was partially covered in [Can I dismiss items from the flag queue?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129373/can-i-dismiss-items-from-the-flag-queue)

Comment: That's certainly related; not precisely the same, but related.

Comment: can you post a mockup? would there be too many options?

Comment: @waffles I've taken the liberty to draw such a mockup hopefully Jonathan here won't mind. :)

Comment: Strongly related: [Add ignore button to suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84102/add-ignore-button-to-suggested-edits)

Comment: @waffles: Brock Adams more or less has what I had in mind - and my ASCII art abilities really won't help you any. I'm not sure about resizing the buttons to different sizes; I think they should be 'neutral' and all the same size.  I'd be fine with 'Ignore' instead of 'Pass'.   If the 'Hide posts' option means I don't get to see those that I've approved or rejected, that's fine too; better to simply not show again (on refresh) those edits that have been acted on. One tricky bit might be that different people should see different counts of numbers of outstanding edits.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I very much agree with your suggestion (I've always wanted to pass on things in the queue in know I will never get to for one of the reasons you outlined), and I also agree with Brock Adams' answer too (minus the button resizing) but does it make sense to accept his answer right now? Since this is a `feature-request` shouldn't you maybe way for a `status-` verdict?

Comment: @BenLee: Dunno what the protocol is.  I have accepted Ben's answer as representing the community consensus on what should be done (and it's only slightly better than what I had in mind, as he added the 'Hide' option).  What actually happens next is now up to the Higher Mortals who operate StackExchange...they get to decide whether it is implementable and so on.  I would be getting buzzed by the system to select an answer if I don't accept one.  So, I'm open to persuasion that I should not be accepting anything yet, but at this instant think what I've done is reasonably correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, actually you're probably right. The people with privs to add `status-` tags probably also have a list of to-be-resolved `feature-request`s somewhere, regardless of whether the question has an accepted answer or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alternate mockup:

Please add this to the top of the page and have it checked by default:

[image: Kickass option needed]

Then, the idea of an "ignore" button is fine (and the flagging tools really need it), but too many options can scare off some users.

There is also, IMO, a real problem with too many poor, or incomplete edits being approved (that is just my opinion, I'm not going to dig up the proof right now).

So add a 4th option, but weight the options to guide the reviewer into making the right choice:

[image: Add an Ignore button]

Comment: Yes, I've always thought that page needed more freehand circles.

Comment: Thanks; the part at bottom right is more or less what I had in mind.  The default-selected option at the top is an embellishment I hadn't thought of; on the whole, a refresh of the edit list should simply not show those posts I've given a verdict on.  There might need to be a count explanation: 'There are also 13 suggested edits that you have already processed' (to explain why the count says 28 and you only see 15), if the per-user counts are too tricky.

Comment: Some people might wish to see posts they've already judged for some reason, and it's poor practice, IMO, to unilaterally change how a page/feature works without giving the crusty fogies (if any) a way to preserve the old behavior.  Hence the proposed checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mockup - this will appear when hovering over a suggested edit and titled "ignore":

[image: mockup]

I also suggest that it will be reversible, e.g. list of ignored suggestions where you can expand any of them back.

Another option: don't include or always put last suggestions tagged with any tag that is in the Ignored Tags list of the user, unless there is also a tag from the Favorite Tags list.

Comment: I'm for the idea, but you seriously couldn't come up with a better "x" button? :P

Comment: @Purmou my graphic design skills are really poor - but this should give the general idea, no? :)

Comment: That is one ugly blue "X" button. Could we maybe use the same one that's already used on pop-up dialogs, like "close"? Or perhaps make it a little "lighter" than that, with a gray background instead of a black?

Comment: @The OK OK don't shoot me - the existing X from pop up dialogs was taken. :)

Comment: @Purmou how about now? Not my design so can't blame me. :)