# Does reviewing posts remove them from review list?

Tags: support, review, revisions-list

My question is quite simple : when I review a post (from the review link), and improve, does it remove it from the review list ?

I love the prettify function, and I am more encline to read pretty post, so I edit as many post as possible for adding syntax highlighting. But I would be afraid if other reviewers cannot see them anymore in this list ...

It's really difficult to see it by myself, because the list is always moving (and asynchronous  way of working of StackExange might introduce some difficulties to see it).

Comment: Yes, it really does remove it. Rather pointless if it didn't.

Comment: Indeed it is a geater responsability than I thought ...

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean, if I review a post, I should check it all ways : gramatical, title relevance, tags, syntax highlighting, not just a simple improvement like in other posts.

Comment: Well, that would be best :)

Comment: Yes, but as you maybe noticed, I'm not an english native speaker, and syntax highliting or title relevance are easier (and quicker when I don't have too much time to edit) to improve. But if it removes the thread from the list, I should maybe let it to less casual reviewers ...

Comment: That's a value judgement. I am not a native speaker, but one learns...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't yet have the ability to officially review posts (you need the Strunk & White badge), then no, those posts will not be affected by you reviewing them.

Assuming you have the privilege, once *you* review a post, it will be removed from *your* view so you don't have to review it again. Posts are not, however, removed from the review queue entirely until a **second person** reviews the post as well. So, it actually takes two people for a post to be counted as "reviewed" but you will not see it twice. It is also possible that more than two people will see the post if someone has the page loaded already after the second person reviews the post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was exactly was I looking for ! Is it mentionned somewhere ? I didn't find it in old questions, nor in FAQ. I took a look at privileges, but did not found it. If I missed something, tell me. If not, shouldn't it be written "clearly" ?

Comment: Here's the [official post about its implementation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110414).