# Keep posts flagged spam or offensive in the review queue

Tags: feature-request, flags, review, offensive

Currently, [according to Waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them), answers or questions that have been "reviewed" are suppressed if more than 2 people have reviewed them.

This is obviously a a Good Thing <sup>TM</sup>, however, it does mean that if two people review a question or answer and then flag it as spam or offensive then it disppears from the review queue.

[This one is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330399/redirecting-user-back-to-originally-desired-url-after-login/11358197#11358197). It's only just been closed after 2 hours; mainly, I believe, because it disappeared from the `/review/first-answers` and `/review/late-answers` tabs.

This semi-defeats the point of these flags, which is to allow the community at large to remove [highly objectionable material](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work) without the need for moderator intervention, for instance if there's not one logged on at that time to review offensive flags.

My [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is that if a majority of people reviewing a question or answer have marked it as spam, or offensive, then that post should not be removed from the `/review` tab.

The reason for the majority is to stop abusive flagging and / or to ensure that it is actually offensive. As two people are required to review something if one of them flags a post as offensive it will remain in the review list. If a further person reviews the post and does not flag it the post will be removed. If they do then it will stay.

Answer (score 1):

I've observed spam sit around for many hours especially when it's often tagged with a fairly random tag that few if anyone would follow. Even on smaller sites where tag filtering is used less often it can still be problematic because after a few flags on the first post / late answer queue they are often followed by an edit or answer by a trusted user on the question that can leave the reason it was bumped initially not apparent.

The only avenue of abuse I can see with your proposal is that when someone sees something on a queue with a link and several downvotes a robo-reviewer might decide they are probably implicit spam / offensive flags and decide to pile on another flag. That could easily be mitigated by either showing a zero vote count or ignoring the implicit downvotes. I think the former would be best because many users seems to flag as well as downvote spam / offensive posts and other than that small tweak this sounds like an excellent feature request.