# How about the ability to hide suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, suggested-edits

After using the suggested edits feature for a bit I found that I do not have the technical knowledge for some suggested edits to make a decision.

So it just sits there.

How about a feature that allows me to hide suggested edits. So if there is an edit I don't have enough knowledge to approve or reject, I can just hide it.

This probably does not seem that important now but when users start figuring this out and using the suggested edit feature more, it will be pretty important to be able to do this.

Comment: Related - same thing for `/review` http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/the-review-page-needs-to-be-able-to-handle-more-than-just-problem-posts

Comment: Isn't the correctness mainly the responsibility of the editor, who (when registered) will be shown as such in the revision history?

Comment: There is an inherit responsibility with the auditors to make correct decisions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add "ignore" button to suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84102/add-ignore-button-to-suggested-edits)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather have the suggested edits filtered by tags, so you did not see them unless you had more than the normal number of upvotes for at least one of the tags.

But that would slow down the system.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like a feature to hide or abstain from voting on suggested edits.  There's one in the queue today where the edit is one I don't know is technically correct, but the answer it is an edit on is hundreds of lines long and it is cluttering up the page.

I am very tempted to reject it (it has one reject vote already) just to make it go away, but that would be wrong, since it might be a valid change.