# Can the suggested edit page *not* show the edits you've already voted on?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Having the questions you've already voted on makes it more work to find things that still need attention.

Note, I am talking about when you refresh the page, not the JavaScript action that happens immediately after you action an item.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122368/filter-out-already-processed-items-from-the-suggested-edits

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I solved the problem by not bothering with doing edits anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just reviewing now and wanted to asked exactly for the same feature. It would really make reviewing much more fluent! Just hide those edits immediately after you vote to Approve or Reject!

Maybe there could be a possibility to show these edits (e.g. by some switch/filter), but it is not necessary.

Comment: I'd actually like it to go further, and let me "skip" edits. With the random sorting, I see the same edits over and over and over and over and over and over. I realize that'd be a fair amount of work for the devs (persisting those skipped edits). They wouldn't *have* to store it on the DB though - I'd be happy with a LocalStorage solution, even.

Comment: @RobHruska, but the information on what you voted on already **is** in the DB! So in fact no new storage is needed here! It writes "You already voted to accept this edit...", so in fact the change could be quite easy - just don't display it then!

Comment: Well, I'm talking about the ones that I don't act on (i.e. skipped). I'd rather have a "Skip" button than have to scroll through ones I've seen half a dozen times.

Comment: But @Rob, that's a [completely different discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84102/add-ignore-button-to-suggested-edits/127844).

Comment: No disagreement there - I just like to take the opportunity to go on a rant about it whenever I can :)

Comment: +1: I just came over here to ask this same question