# Filter out already processed items from the "suggested edits"

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UI annoyances in the suggested edit review on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow)

I'm trying to help out with clearing the Suggested Edits queue at SO.

When it's now close to 100 entries, we are shown 30 random entries at a time. Processing half of these and pressing Show more, I get another set of 30 entries **including a whole lot of those already processed**. Not very efficient!

Could we either hide the ones that I have already voted on, or allow me to scroll sequentially through **all** of them?

---

Now it is down to 86 edits in the edit queue, and we are back to three pages of suggested edits.

Does this happen just between 90 and 100? Could we just turn it off, in that case?

<sub>I'm out of votes anyway for today.</sub>

Comment: I think a variant of this was just asked within the last few days. I'm struggling to find it, though.

Comment: There has been suggestions to filter them out (suggested when I wrote the question), which seemed hard to do. A problem is that when there are like 60 edits we get two pages to check, but when 90+ (or so) we get 30 *random* at a time. Selecting 30 out of 90 multiple times gets you *a lot* of dupes!

Comment: Yeah, for sure. The reviewing process can be a bit cumbersome. I keep trying to think of ways to fix it and write up a meta question, but I struggle with the ideal way to fix it.

Comment: [Here's what I was looking for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow#comment322481_96426) - not a duplicate, but another list of annoyances/inconsistencies. I guess it was asked a while back but came back to life with the bounty.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! I wholeheartedly support any move to get rid of the random ordering that gives me back those suggestions I've already dealt with or skipped because I didn't know whether to approve or reject. I won't mind seeing them again if there remain none I haven't seen before, but searching the few new ones among the previously skipped is freaking annoying.