# Suggested Edits vs Flagged Posts Display in Moderation Tools

Tags: feature-request, support

I religiously take out time every day specifically for `Review Suggested Edits` and `Flagged Posts`. This question is about a small but useful `Feature` which will really make my life easier. :)

When I action a post (esp `Not an Answer`) from [Flagged Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged), It accepts my input and then disappears from `my` screen if I refresh the page. Please see this snapshot.

[image]

However in the `Review Suggested Edits`, after I approve/reject a particular edit, it still remains on my screen even after I refresh the page.. Please see this snapshot

[image]

Would it be possible, if we could have the same functionality shared in `Review Suggested Edits`? The reason I request this is because after reviewing approx 30-40 edits, the page is full of  "**You have voted to approve/reject this edit - awaiting more votes.**" and it is really annoying to skim through those and find the posts which are still not actioned.

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to Matt for the links. This question apparently is a dup of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow). I am requesting closing of this question and offering a bounty on that question.

Comment: +100, but a dupe.

Comment: @Matt: Thank you :) I searched for 10 minutes before I posted this question but couldn't find a question which addresses this feature. Could you please help me with the link. So that if that link addresses this issue then I can close my question. Thanks again :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/can-the-suggested-edit-page-not-show-the-edits-youve-already-voted-on, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122368/filter-out-already-processed-items-from-the-suggested-edits (to name a few). (I did https://www.google.com/?q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com%20dont%20show%20suggested%20edits%20already%20voted%20on)

Comment: @Matt: Thank you. Much appreciated. What do you suggest? Should I close this question? Also I couldn't find any answers in those posts? Would you recommend mentioning those links in my question and add that they were never answered?

Comment: @Matt: BTW, I use FF so cannot use the Chrome extension :)

Comment: As this question is a dupe, I'd close it as a dupe of the most popular [meta-tag:feature-request] (this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow), and perhaps start a bounty on the question (the "Draw Attention" or " Authoritative reference needed" bounty reasons would be appropiate here).

Comment: @Matt: I am not deleting the above question. In fact I have edited it and flagged it as a duplicate so that it may help anyone who comes searching and lands on this thread. Thanks again Matt. Much appreciated.

Comment: BOUNTY OFFERED as promised. Thanks for helping me out here @Matt.