# Correctly page the suggested-edits queue

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

When I go onto page two, it often contains edits I have decided not to act on.
I think the problem is that a new SQL query is done, that often returns less results for the first page.  So can you.  (Assume the page is ordered on X)

> Return a page worth of results that are greater (on X) then the last
>   item on the preceding page.  If was done, then this “fix” would not be
>   needed

If Add [“ignore” option to suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84102/add-ignore-option-to-suggested-edits)  was done, then this “fix” would not be needed