# Order suggested edit queue by oldest first rather than randomly

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, suggested-edits, review

**Situation:** The suggested edit queue on Stack Overflow [has been full](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129850/do-we-need-a-bat-signal-on-meta-calling-in-help-when-the-edit-queue-is-full) for the past few days.

**Scenario**: I pop along and get shown 30 *random* suggested edits. I vote on them so all of them now have 1 vote (either a reject or accept).

Another user pops along and gets shown 30 *random* (and for the purpose of this argument, entirely different) edits. They vote on all of them so they all have 1 vote each.

*The suggested edit queue is still full!*

---

If the suggested edits were ordered *consistently* however, users visiting the suggested edit queue would get shown **the same** suggested edits, and if the scenario mentioned above was repeated, the size of the queue would shrink.

---

Additional benefits;

1. The pagination [*would actually work*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100255/correctly-page-the-suggested-edits-queue).
2. The chances of suggestions getting approved in the order they were posted would increase; rather than some suggestions sitting in the queue for hours, whilst others get accepted immediately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, I am declining this. The reasoning for the random ordering is to help avoid "double work" from happening.

If every voter sees the same list, it is quite likely that when the queue is large a lot of suggestions will get 3-4 or 5 votes as opposed to the required 2.

I would prefer to allow you to inform us that you "do not care" about an edit, that way each time you look at 30 you will see a new list.

Answer (score 8):

I emphatically support killing the random sorting of the suggested edit queue. Or at least give the option to disable it.

The situation I find terribly annoying is when the queue is full and I go through the first page, I vote on 20 suggestions, say, the others I don't know whether they should be accepted or rejected. Then I fetch the next 50. At least half of them are suggestions I already saw in the first batch. From the third batch on, I hardly ever see a new suggestion.

Any sort of ordering that would make me see only not-yet-seen suggestions until I've seen them all would be a big improvement.

Comment: what about ['edit weight' feature - similar to flag weight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129839/lowered-editing-threshold-for-avid-editors/129853#129853 "suggested here") "a measure of how well a user proposes edits... used behind the scenes for ordering edits in each site's edit queue"

Comment: There's one downside to such an ordering. If the suggestions of good proposers come first, you'll have spent all your votes before you reach the bad ones to reject. If they come last, they'll be in the queue longer than necessary. But any sort of consistent ordering would be an improvement, IMO.

Comment: _out of the votes_ I see that's a good point. I think ["Bat-Signal"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129850/do-we-need-a-bat-signal-on-meta-calling-in-help-when-the-edit-queue-is-full "suggested here") or some other way to notify diamond mods on the queue issue would make sense for cases like that, no matter how it is ordered

Comment: I am empathetic to a "I don't know" button for edits, also think the random should bias towards stuff you are likely to be able to handle

Comment: An "I don't know" button would be great.