# Activating Bat Signal: Pay more attention to Edit Queue during Great Tag Cleanup

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Due (largely) to the massive influx of edits because of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012, the suggested edit queue is *very **very*** nearly full.

To stop the cleanup grinding to a halt (users won't be able to edit once the queue is full), **can those with the approve-edit-privilege pay extra attention to the queue size until we're done?**

In other words... [can we activate the bat signal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129850/do-we-need-a-bat-signal-on-meta-calling-in-help-when-the-edit-queue-is-full)

[image]

Comment: Some of the questions those edits are on look like they'd be better of deleted than edited. (Mostly the [tag:future] ones that are looking for speculation)

Comment: Vote to delete or flag to delete old crap questions, don't edit them.

Comment: @sixlettervariables And flag for moderator attention if they are too old to gain enough close/delete votes.

Comment: You used the wrong symbol :( http://i.stack.imgur.com/HWIXw.png

Comment: It would be great to make the edit queue visible to everyone with edit privileges at times like this.

Comment: http://se-suggested-edits.heroku.com/

Comment: @random - great! Thanks

Comment: seems like the 50 vote cap is a bit inconvenient during this time of heightened activity. I just burned though 50 votes and the edit queue was bigger at the end than when I started!

Comment: Saw the link in chat, dropped it here. Guessing it's a look at the latest made, not the latest pending @mrl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently at 154... Most of them by:

1. [vyegorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1154462/vyegorov?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) doing quite a good job of cleaning up questions from what I've seen.
2. [whiteknight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664054/whiteknight?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) who seems to be removing [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) on a number of off-topic closed questions.

According to Waffles answer on [Do we need a Bat-Signal on Meta, calling in help when the edit queue is full?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129850/do-we-need-a-bat-signal-on-meta-calling-in-help-when-the-edit-queue-is-full), the extended queue is almost full...

---

One last bump because I'm out of votes and it's still at 144. Over to you all...