# Please allow the suggested edit queue to be filtered by tag

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow us to filter Suggested Edits by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125169/allow-us-to-filter-suggested-edits-by-tag)

With the length of Stack Overflow's [suggested edit queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) [spiraling ever higher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130921/activating-bat-signal-pay-more-attention-to-edit-queue-during-great-tag-cleanup), we need all the help we can get to keep it from filling up entirely.

However, edits of code often require some expertise. I often see Objective C code being "corrected", but I don't know if the edits are valid or not.

Can the queue be made sortable/filterable? I'd love to thin the 100 suggestions down to 15 Java-tagged edits and run through *those* instead of trying to tackle the entire list.

Comment: Well how about that