# Add the blink tag to the suggested edit indicator when the queue approaches capacity

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, suggested-edits, review

Okay, maybe making it blink is going too far, but drawing attention to it seems to work.  [Call to arm: Suggested edit queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138906/1288) was posted earlier today, and the edit queue dropped from 200 down to 100 in about an hour.  (So the problem wasn't that users with the power to approve edits were out of votes, they simply didn't notice that the queue was full.)

Instead of relying on extremely localized posts on Meta to draw people's attention to suggested edits, maybe this could be automated.  **Can you change the color of the indicator from brown to red when the queue reaches (or as it approaches) capacity?**

Comment: I think it should [fire lasers](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/make-the-mothership-shoot-its-lasers-on-hover) and burst into flames. I'll put out a plate of bacon and we'll wait for Jin to come along and make magic happen.

Comment: @TimStone `status-completed`  Yes!  We have the technology!

Comment: Or big red arrows to be drawn on the screen, pointing to the link. Also, similar but not necessarily related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134220/tell-us-when-the-suggested-edit-queue-is-full-busy-on-stackoverflow

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XPhBq.png

Comment: I ran out of edit votes, but didn't realize until I'd spent another 5 minutes apparently receiving the message *"out of votes"* :(

Comment: If people visit the review page, I think they would know that the suggested edit queue is full just by looking at the number. The problem is that I don't think people visit it that often. Hence the queue may fill up to its max capacity. I think the idea of random can work (size aside): we can put the number of posts in suggested edit queue right next to the review link (not hover text, though).

Comment: See also [Do we need a Bat-Signal on Meta, calling in help when the edit queue is full?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129850) [Activating Bat Signal: Pay more attention to Edit Queue during Great Tag Cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130921) [Please make the pending suggested edit indicator visible at 5k rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128889) and I think there's a couple more I can't find right now.