# Yet Another Disabled Edit Option, but edit url is accessible

Tags: bug, edits, hyperlinks

I know there are many super down-voted posts in meta about disabled edit options.

To my experience, when the edit option is disabled for a non-closed relatively recent post, it means that I cannot edit that post (and normally any other posts).

For example, it happens to me when I had five edits waiting for review.

But, today I found the edit link on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403502/oerror-errno-26-text-file-busy-myvirtualenv-bin-python) and its comments are disabled for me, while I have access to its [edit url](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40403502/edit) directly.

I am not sure based on what "policies", I am not able to edit that specific post, but I am pretty sure I should receive an error message when I am typing the edit url in the address bar. (or maybe the edit link should be enabled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no other pending edit or alike.. What does the tooltip say when you hover the edit link?

Comment: There are more possible reasons: [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/209901). It is not disabled to me, so I suspect it may have to do with you as a user. However, you don't have rejected suggested edits. Do you still experience it?

Comment: The edit button is available for me. Directly

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the suggested edit review queue was full when you took that screenshot.

As said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84398/152859), the queue size is 200 on Stack Overflow. Right now there are 128 pending edits, but most likely when you took the screenshot there was a temporary peak. The [stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) shows 2,356 reviews today, which is a lot, so good chance that was indeed the case.

Next time, hover over the disabled link with the mouse cursor, and you'll see the reason.

Comment: `200` ? new information

Comment: @SagarV [new for almost five years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129894/152859), yes. :) (*increased the queue size to 200 as a stop gap*)

Comment: I missed a lot. almost half of SO. I created my profile for more than 3 years but become active in this feb only.

Comment: _increased the queue size to 200 as a stop gap_ what is the size of Close vote quese , I think `10K` correct?

Comment: @SagarV I don't think there is a limit to other queues, only suggested edits, since other actions are already rate limited on their own. (e.g. every user can cast X amount of flags or Y amount of close votes, while there is no limit how many edits a single user can suggest.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Triage (only on Stack Overflow) is also capped. The cap used to be 100; I think it was increased but I don't remember to what.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom [Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331666/has-there-been-an-increment-of-triage-review-limits/331667#331667) holds a max of 200 posts to review.

Comment: Hovering over the link it (still) says "suggested edit queue is full". But, shouldn't the edit url be inaccessible? Just disabling a link is enough?

Comment: Currently at 5:24 (EST), I can see there are 160 review in the review stats, but still the edit option is unavailable

Comment: @AfshinMoazami Yes if the queue is really full it should also prevent editing in the direct URL. Try clearing your browser cache, reload with CTRL+F5 and see if it helps.

Comment: Not really. It is not a browser cache issue. I am not sure if I can submit the edit, but I am pretty sure I can reach the editor