# Could an option be added to /review to only show 0- or downvoted posts?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

After going through posts in the /review page, one of the trends that I noticed was that very few non-answers were upvoted at all.  Now that results are presented in random groupings if a query has more than a certain number of results, there isn't a way to sort these results by votes or by those which perform worst on the review algorithm.

A lot of short but good answers are now popping up in the low quality posts tab's random groupings, which is making it harder to find true non-answers.  Almost all of the upvoted answers that appear here are actual answers and should be left alone.  Very few of the non-answers get voted up by anyone, because of their lack of content.

If we had an option on the /review page to filter the low quality posts to only those at 0 votes or lower, I think it would make the random groupings more effective in showing potential answers to be removed, as well as questions that may need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is now the default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89189/remove-accepted-answers-and-answers-with-many-upvotes-from-the-low-quality-list/164223#164223).

It's possible that we'll some day improve the heuristics enough to be confident that some subset of up-voted posts have sufficiently serious quality issues to warrant review (or just redirect "low-quality" moderator flags) but until then we're focusing on those that haven't attracted votes (or have attracted down-votes).

Answer (score 6):

I think that would be a mistake:

- Some (new?) users upvote any and all answers to their questions.
- Just because something is popular, it does not mean that it's helpful, on-topic or not offensive.
- If such an option was available, many (most?) reviewers would enable it and lots of posts would slip through the cracks.

I would prefer, instead, a ["mark as OK" flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74249/153998) which would allow a post to be removed from the review system if e.g. 5 reviewers with a reputation of, say, over 2000 thought that it was acceptable. I, for one, am getting tired of reviewing the same posts over and over again...

Comment: "Mark as OK" is also available now (in the form of "Looks Good").