# Remove accepted answers and answers with many upvotes from the Low quality list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

Looking over the Review section on Stack Overflow I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824830/java-simplify-the-syntax/5825003#5825003) answer; it's got 8 upvotes (mine included) and no downvotes. Why would such an answer be considered low quality? Looking over the list, there's another answer with 3 upvotes and 2 accepted answers down the list.

How exactly do you determine that an answer is low quality? I don't think answers with a lot of upvotes belong on that list. The same goes for accepted answers with more than 1 or 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new /review queues, accepted answers and answers scoring > *threshold* are exempt.

*Threshold* is currently 0.

Answer (score 5):

I think the number of votes is ignored in the heuristic that checks for *possible* poor answers. Length is an important indicator. More details can be found in ["Heuristics for detecting a bad answer?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer), which was the start of the `/review` page.

Notice that this answer is indeed correct, but the accepted answer is a bit better because it also explains the XOR operator, which might not be known to everyone. It's always better if you not only answer the current question, but help users answer possible future questions themselves.

Comment: It would seem a bit silly to ignore votes. I'm not sure how you'd be able to game the system in order to get 8 upvotes.

Comment: @alex: I don't know whether you noticed this a lot, but if it really bothers you, you can create a new `[feature-request]` (or rewrite the current post) to filter out high-voted questions and answers from the "low quality" list.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. On a slightly unrelated note, were you trying be ironic?

Comment: @alex: With my previous comment? No, but I have a habit of talking to Stack Exchange newcomers on the WordPress site, so I explain a lot about the system in my comments - and only then noticed your high reputation.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm not exactly new to the site...

Comment: @alex if you feel so strongly about it, why don't you edit that answer to provide a fuller explanation and make it more awesome? That would have certainly taken less time than asking about it on meta, no?

Comment: @Jeff why? I like the answer the way it is; I don't consider it low quality and, judging by the 12 upvotes and 0 downvotes, neither does anyone else. That's why I asked on meta, because I don't understand why certain posts are considered low quality when they're clearly not.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are problems with the current low quality answer set-up.

Here is an example of an answer marked low quality: [Dropping extra column in Tab delim file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159345/dropping-extra-column-in-tab-delim-file/7159474#7159474)

It has five up votes and a number of enthusiastic comments.

I recently tried to answer a question with one line and the answer was moved to a comment. I doubt that it is intended that I should blither for several lines to get a short answer past the system, but it is tempting.