# Can the 'low quality post' tab in the 'Review' section have a rep filter?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, review

I keep getting users with greater than 10,000 rep points showing up on the 'Low Quality Posts' tab (https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?pagesize=15&filter=day)

Can you just filter them out with the understanding that if you have more than say 5,000 points you pretty much know how not to answer a question?

Answer (score 8):

I think it could be taken into account, but posts from high-rep users should still appear on that tab for certain reasons (answers that are nothing but a link, for example).  I see a few answers that are there right now evidently just because they're very short.  I agree that a 10K user should know if two lines of code answers the question, so I think those could be safely excluded.

Answer (score 2):

Reputation is a rough indication of valued participation, but certainly *not* a guarantee of consistent quality. While we do now [exclude posts that someone has indicated are useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80120/could-an-option-be-added-to-review-to-only-show-0-or-downvoted-posts/164229#164229), there's no way to [earn your bullshit](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2356568) as far as the system is concerned.