# Warn users of Low Quality Posts before they actually post it

Tags: feature-request

Ok, so [my first publish](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/167900/1) of this Question had 68 characters and I was able to publish it without any warning.

What prompted me this idea is that today I met an Answer from a 1k user that was Twitter-length.
Damn, he should know better, why do I have to call his attention to that if the system can do it?

Got angry (only in my head, not in my comment to the A) because of the relation Rep/Quality, but of course some kind of warning would be welcomed independently of Rep.

`<start-pop-up>`
<kbd>Hey, this is not Twitter and your Q/A will show up in the Low Quality review, are you sure? Yes/No</kbd>
`<end-pop-up>`

---

Related Q&A's

- [Low quality posts and experienced users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116056/185667)
- [Is the "low quality" system unfair to concise programming languages?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141281/185667)
- [Why do I get exactly the same comment by different users for my link-only answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143663/185667)

Comment: I expect it to be *exactly* 6 minutes too...

Comment: @animuson, it will, I'm here and it's already written ;)

Comment: [68 characters](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/0ea3f4b3-e1c2-4565-8dbf-a548b543fc14/view-source)

Comment: I'm not sure about this. It could be used to game the LQ algorithm :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I kind of like the idea I'm not sure what the benefit of it would be. If it's only a hint that it might show up in the [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) queue and can simply be dismissed, isn't there a high chance that the OP would do so?

Sometimes a question or an answer doesn't need to be very long. That's why it's hard to automatically determine whether the length is appropriate. See for example this very short question using slightly more characters (209) than a Twitter post. It was highly upvoted and got an even shorter answer that solved it:

[When is a problem too complex for a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230517/1456376)

Comment: The benefit that when reviewing or finding such posts one has only to analyze: 1) Is it really low quality? 2) Yes: down-vote or vote to close/delete. 3) The user was warned, no comments, end of story.

Answer (score 1):

Some minimum length is just one criterion one could set for a 'good-enough' post, such as one has to change at least 6 characters to make an edit, though the number would probably end up being arbitrary (100 characters? 200?).

Other suggestions:

- It might be better to ask that the user include some code (since that is normally required of SO posts) by checking they have included at least one sequence of 4 spaces for code indenting. Or, if we're being liberal, at least something between some `` characters. Example: <kbd>You don't seem to have included any code in your post. Make sure you have included some code and that it is formatted correctly.</kbd>
- We could make sure the user is actually asking a question by checking for at least one sentence-end question-mark, e.g. <kbd>You don't seem to have asked any questions in this post. Please think carefully about why you are posting.</kbd>

Neither of these suggestions would filter all bad posts but they could prompt the user to think about formatting and phrasing the question more carefully as they are writing. There are always the free downvotes for questions that still show up badly after this process.