# Approve question flag in /review

Tags: feature-request, flags, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The /review page needs to be able to handle more than just problem posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/the-review-page-needs-to-be-able-to-handle-more-than-just-problem-posts)

I think that in the https://stackoverflow.com/review page there should be a "flag as okay" button that once (3? can change) members have clicked it, it will remove that question from the search for "First Question"/"First Answer" etc

This will clean up the question list and thus make it easier to review.

Comment: @PopularDemand Could you merge my content with your question?

Comment: okay, I did.

Comment: @PopularDemand Thank you - much appreciated, this should have been pushed through due to your question by now anyway, it is quite a hinderance...