# Ability to vote-to-remove posts from the /review page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

I propose that on the `/review` page, there should be the ability for us to vote the posts as "Not low quality". After a post has received *X* number of votes, it should be removed from the `/review` page.

Probably (similar to how the "edit" system works), more than one vote would be required to *remove* it from the `/review` page.

The reason for this is that all the users who are going to the `/review` page are looking at some random subset of the **same** set of posts. It's not the best use of our time. If, as a group, we could remove posts that don't have any problems, none of us will be sifting through the same posts that **other people have already gone through**.

Comment: How about upvoting them?

Comment: @Cody: I didn't realise that removed them from the list. There's questions in the list that have upvoted **and** have been accepted as the best answer.

Comment: Matt, upvoting them does not remove them from the list. I believe you are stuck sifting through the randomly assorted posts, regardless of if you or others have already deemed the post to be OK or not, by flagging, editing, upvoting, or doing nothing. I support this idea fully, but doubt it will be implemented.

Comment: Right, I didn't mean it would remove them. See also: [Approve question flag in /review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82062/approve-question-flag-in-review), [The /review page needs to be able to handle more than just problem posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/the-review-page-needs-to-be-able-to-handle-more-than-just-problem-posts)

Comment: Maybe we could at least have the functionality to remove something from /review *for ourselves*? Once I've read through something and decided it is okay, it is frustrating to see it again a few hours later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already completed. If 2 reviewers (users with Strunk & White) click on the "review question / answer" link it will vanish from the global list.