# Late Answer Filtering

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, moderation

I've been going through the answers and questions in the [Review area](https://stackoverflow.com/review) much more frequently and am finding it frustrating that there is no filtering, only a return of random answers and questions.

It would be nicer if the review area remembered the questions and answers that I've seen and didn't show me those again. It would eliminate a lot of noise since the majority of the results are legitimate and don't need to be reviewed again.

Can filtering be implemented in the review area so that only answers and questions that I haven't reviewed before are seen?

**Edit**: plus it would facilitate my OCD in getting the number of posts to review down to 0 :D

Comment: I think it would also be productive to filter late answers that are not first posts, there's a lot of duplication there.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104665/newest-sort-order-for-review-on-smaller-sites

Comment: @jon a lot of spam materalizes as late answers, whether it's the user's first post or not..

Comment: @Jeff Understood.  I guess I mapped my own workflow into the proposal in my comment, I tend to go from one to the other and see a lot of repeats.  I do still like Gavin's idea, though.

Answer (score 2):

If they're not going to sort by date, then some filtering would be nice.

Maybe have it hinge on the reviewer clicking 'ok' somewhere, as per [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102118/ability-to-vote-to-remove-posts-from-the-review-page) [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/the-review-page-needs-to-be-able-to-handle-more-than-just-problem-posts) [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103607/can-we-cast-a-vote-flag-mark-in-some-way-review-posts-to-basically-say-theyre-ok) [requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them).

Comment: Thanks for grabbing those related questions.

Answer (score 2):

There's no rational way to "inspect" hundreds of posts, so we move to random sampling.

If you filter by tag to get the list down to 90 or below, pagination is restored. So click those tags on the right if you want a paginated list.

Comment: My concern is that I read and reread the same posts. I am normally able to read a couple of words and skip old ones, but some I don't recognize right away.  Potentially, I can mentally sort by timestamps, but there's a chance that a few posts have not been chosen by the system.  Tag filtering definitely works, I just think that some way to check off or "whitelist" Qs or As that have already gone by a dozen times might make it more efficient.  Of course, whitelisting for our own reference wouldn't necessitate pulling those posts from the pool, so it wouldn't introduce a bias.