# Can we cast a vote/flag/mark in some way review posts to basically say they're ok?

Tags: feature-request, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow marking posts as reviewed on /review and hide them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75953/allow-marking-posts-as-reviewed-on-review-and-hide-them)

When going through the Review page there a lots of things the automatic processing catches that aren't really bad posts.  Also sometimes, a post needs a little help, and I can edit it so it's ok.

How about a way for reviewers to vote/flag/mark these posts that are ok, and when enough accumulate (maybe 6) then they fall off of the review list?

Maybe a vote/flag/mark could add to the quality score.