# Newest sort order for review on smaller sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, sorting

On the review page on Stack Overflow, [the ordering is random](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72419/random-sort-order-on-review-pages) while on the smaller sites with less than 60 questions in review it is by "current" (whatever that means).

On the smaller sites could we get a newest sort order, maybe by option, so that when we check review the newest ones will be at the top?  I've already gone through all the posts on Super User, but to really check, I have to go through them all again every time I go to the review tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completed, also I added an option to disable random ordering.

[image: custom sort]

[image: disable random]

Comment: I didn't see the `Newest First` link on the SU page, is it still to be rolled out?

Comment: to be rolled out today ... just pushed the code

Comment: that works great, can we make it sticky?