# Sort review posts by time?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It's great that we are no longer limited to the random sort order, yet I'd like to see an option to be able to sort those results by post time, so we finally get a **fixed** order on the results (the current vote induced order can change over time).

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been implemented (as mentioned in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104665/newest-sort-order-for-review-on-smaller-sites/106997#106997)).

You now have the several sort options. These are <strike>hidden</strike> listed in the sidebar just after the "*Tag Summary*".

[image: This image was shamelessly stolen from linked post]

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather have them grouped by tag, at least for *edit reviews*.

I don't feel like I should judge whether some edit is appropriate when it is done to some question's source code in a tag I never read any questions in. So let me pick the tags I feel like I know something about and judge those edits.

As it is, I rarely ever look at the pending edit reviews, because it's mostly stuff I wouldn't want to judge.

Comment: That might make sense for edit suggestions, but what about first and late answers? Imagine I want to go through all first answers, flagging "me too" and similar posts.

Comment: @htorque: Oops, I didn't think of any reviews besides edits. I'll modify my answer.