# Why isn't "Newest first" the standard sorting option on the review pages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Before you insta-dupe-close this - Yes, I have read the following similar question: [Newest sort order for review on smaller sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104665/newest-sort-order-for-review-on-smaller-sites)

I'm just asking why newest first isn't the standard option? It's so much easier to see what you haven't seen when having it sorted with the newest posts first.