# How does the review-system work?

Tags: discussion, review

I'm now allowed to visit the review pages. What I understood from reading hints here and there, is: There are newbies, which might do a lousy layout, bad questions which aren't real questions, bad answers and so on.

If we teach the newbies, how to do it right, most of them will be prepared for somehow good answers when they reach a certain rep-limit.

Okay, so the actions of newbies are collected and presented for review, and if they are bad, I can flag them, I can correct them, and I can comment them, to tell the newb to improve something, which I can't do myself.

But how do I signal, that a question or answer is okay? There are a lot of answers which are somehow okay, but I wouldn't vote them up, because there is a better answer, for example.

Does the system recognize, that I inspected a posting (and maybe 3 or 5 or 10 other users), and I didn't flag it, or is it just a negative selection?

Comment: If a question or answer is OK, no action is required. The absence of your action indicates your ambivalence, which is exactly as it should be.

Comment: Don't say noob! There's a difference between newb and noob : http://www.cad-comic.com/cad/20060823 :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Changed `noob` to `newb`. I wasn't aware of the difference.

Comment: A couple of links that might interest you if you are new to reviewing: [How to review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74194/how-to-review-can-we-agree-on-a-review-policy), [Pro-forma comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments).

Comment: @Robert but if you don't do anything, how do you get the question out of the way so you know you don't need to look at it again? or does that happen automatically when you view the answer?

Comment: @Michael: Is there a Dismiss link?  Or is that only available to moderators?

Comment: Not that I see: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/258282/review.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we need an "approve" button, or at least a "don't show me this again" button.

It has been [discussed on chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/jeff-shoots-down-benjols-idea-of-an-ignore-button-in-review), and here is a related question:

[The /review page needs to be able to handle more than just problem posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/the-review-page-needs-to-be-able-to-handle-more-than-just-problem-posts)