# how review works or how to do reviews?

Tags: support, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I see my reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92034/why-cant-i-see-my-reviews)

I Click on review and do review answers but in my profile under activity > review tag it displays you have no reviews done why ? what I am missing in doing reviews or how this review is works ?

Comment: If during the review process you vote to close posts, you can see in the new votes tab in your profile. (Available only for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have [Stunk & White badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) to see review stats. 
It will look like this:

[image]

See

1. [Strunk & White and Review Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111699/178505)
2. [How does the /review page work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74238/how-does-the-review-page-work)
3. [How does the review-system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89880/how-does-the-review-system-work)
4. [Can we agree on a review 'policy'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74194/can-we-agree-on-a-review-policy?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to have the [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) badge in order for your review stats to count and in order for your reviews to contribute to marking posts as "reviewed."
2. The posts you review do not show up there. The "reviews" tab in your activity history displays the **suggested edits** that you have voted to approve or reject. You don't gain that privilege until you have 2,000 reputation along with the full edit privilege.